# bs4 select_one on loop sometimes has lack of a value text and fails how should i fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, exception, beautifulsoup

```
    url=http://www.mercadopublico.cl/Procurement/Modules/RFB/DetailsAcquisition.aspx?idlicitacion=3951-24-L122
    print(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(i).content, "html.parser")
    soup.select("#box_a2 .box_a_text_00")
    licitation_number = soup.select_one("#lblNumLicitacion").text
    responsable = soup.select_one("#lblResponsable").text
    ficha = soup.select_one("#lblFicha2Reclamo").text
    nombre_licitacion=soup.select_one("#lblNombreLicitacion").text
    
    
    try:
        estado_licitacion = soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado").text
    except ValueError:
```

i have severals links where I make my loop

sometimas this part

```
estado_licitacion = soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado").text
```

get erros because does not exist, tryed to fixed with try and except but keep getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

when doesnt exist, the example is done for error, the loop doesnt fail all the time

Comment: you could try handling the AttributeError. instead of ValueError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your element is available in your `soup`:

```
estado_licitacion = e.text if (e:=soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado")) else 'no estato licitation available'
```

**Note** *`walrus operator` requires `Python 3.8` or later to work.**

Alternative for < `Python 3.8`:

```
estado_licitacion = soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado").text if soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado") else 'no estato licitation available'
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

idList = ['3951-24-L122']
data = []
for idlicitacion in idList:
    url=f'http://www.mercadopublico.cl/Procurement/Modules/RFB/DetailsAcquisition.aspx?idlicitacion={idlicitacion}'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

    data.append({
        'licitation_number': e.text if (e:=soup.select_one("#lblNumLicitacion")) else 'no licitation number available',
        'responsable': e.text if (e:=soup.select_one("#lblResponsable")) else 'no responsable available',
        'ficha': e.text if (e:=soup.select_one("#lblFicha2Reclamo")) else 'no ficha available',
        'estado_licitacion': e.text if (e:=soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado")) else 'no estato licitation available'
    })

data
```

###### Output

```
[{'licitation_number': '3951-24-L122', 'responsable': 'CONSULTORIO GENERAL URBANO VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA, Consultorio Victor Domingo Silva', 'ficha': '0', 'estado_licitacion': 'no estato licitation available'}]
```

Comment: hi sonic , you know this used to work just fine, but had some errors regarding http ssl or something and I am getting a max error attemps on the url. Maybe you know how to fix it?

Comment: May something changes, site makes redirects now, so you have to deal with these.

Comment: oh ok , I understand I have to get the new metatag since they are redirecting now

Answer (score 0):

```
if soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado").text:
    estado_licitacion = soup.select_one("#lblFicha1Estado").text
else:
    pass
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I tried these and didn't work ,the one I gave the answer check is the best way to do it , this one fails.

Comment: sorry of that, since english is not my mother language maybe is more difficult to me, I will try harder